# Direct URL to Saiku query

Tags: url, pentaho, olap-cube, saiku

I've been learning and creating a Pentaho biserver for a few days. I already have Saiku working with my first cube. Now it's time to let users access and start using it.

biserver home page still has the evaluation dialog with default users, and to get to Saiku I always need to create a new Saiku Analysis and then a new query. URL shown in browser is always the same, so I can't find out how to bookmark a Saiku new query to get there directly.

I can't lead users to browse those pages, I need a directly URL to Saiku query, that page where we select the cube and have dimensions and measures.

Can somebody help me plz?

Example: say I'm analysing data and discover something interesting. I wanna show it to somebody else. Of course I won't send an email explaining what must go on coumns and rows and what must be filtered. I wanna take a URL and send this URL to many people. It'd be even better if I could save reports and have them listed so that, instead of a big URL, I just point to that list and indicate the name of the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

despite age of post, I've looking for this and wanted to help someone else. The direct access link that solved was:

/pentaho/content/saiku-ui/index.html?biplugin5=true&dimension_prefetch=false#query/open/

If you want to show edit as default view, insert the "DEFAULT_VIEW_STATE=edit" after "biplugin5=true&"

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the generated MDX in Saiku and then build a dashboard with a MDX datasource

**Edit**
You can save the query from Saiku toolbar in the repository of your biserver and then, when your users ask for opening the file, the query directly opens in Saiku, skipping the first page

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not planning on dashboards for now, I just wanna provide the editor for users.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still unable to make it work. I was able to save a `*.saiku` file on public folder and use a URL like `http://host/pentaho/content/saiku-ui/index.html?biplugin5=true&dimension_prefetch=false&userid=anonymousUser&password=1#query/open/%3Apublic%3Amain.saiku/editor`, this makes saiku open directly, but it has no query executed. User still needs to select cube and create a initial query. I want my saved query to load directly, showing a report with measures columns and rows I had when I saved the file.

Comment: Look at the site of saiku : http://wiki.meteorite.bi/display/SAIK/Saiku+Tips+and+Tricks : that should help

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find a section there that helps me :/